# flutter local notification not cancelled

Tags: flutter, dart

My Notification API Code:

```
  static final _notificationPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static Future<void> showShNotification() async {
    tz.initializeTimeZones();

    _notificationPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        4,
        'Some_Title',
        'Some_Body',
        TZDateTime.from(DateTime.now().add(const Duration(seconds:5)),
            getLocation('Asia/Kolkata')),
        await _notificationDetails(),payload: 'some_payload',
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
        UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,);
  }

  static Future _notificationDetails() async {
    return NotificationDetails(
      // All relevant notification details here
    ));
  }

  static Future<void> done(int id) async {
   await _notificationPlugin.cancel(id);
  }
```

In TextButton Widget :

```
onPressed: () async {

 NotificationApi.showShNotification();
 await NotificationApi.done(4); // for cancellation

},
```

Local Notification with the given id(here 4) is not cancelled. It appears after 5 seconds. If I used cancelAll() function of FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin(), only then it is cancelled. Is it a bug or I am doing something wrong?
Kindly help.

EDIT: I found a possible solution to this :

```
 await NotificationApi.showShNotification();
 await NotificationApi.done(4);
```

Not 100% sure. But I am guessing this is due to the fact that the plugin is a bit sluggish.